How to analyze time complexity of an algorithm with different running time
I am confused about the time complexity of algorithms, since the running time of an algorithm is represented by a function of n, f(n).
For example: f(n) = 3n^2 + 5n + 1 = Θ(n^2)
But if an algorithm has multiple f(n), for example:
if statement 1 then
    for i = 1 to n do
        statement 2
        statement 3
        ...


If statement 1 is True, then f(n) = n * constant = Θ(n)
If statement 1 is False, then f(n) = constant = Θ(1)
How do I determine the running time of an algorithm with multiple f(n)?
I don't know how to analyze it, since big-oh big-omega and big-theta are all based on a single function f(n).

for things like this you can still express worst case or best case time complexity. for a better idea of how the algorithm perform on real world data you might want to find average case time complexity too

So an algorithm could have three different time complexity, not just one right? And same for space complexity?

@NaijunWang yes average, best, worst can all be different
